# Why is the containing div for svg taking more space

Tags: html, css, svg

This simple piece of html:

```html
<div style="background:blue">
  <svg width="40" height="40" style="background:red"></svg> some text
</div>
```

You can see that the svg is `40px` but the surrounding div is `44px` high (tested on chrome).

Why. And how to make the surrounding div respect the size of the SVG without an explicit `height` on the surrounding div and keeping the layout `svg+text` in a single line?

Answer (score 20):

The `svg` element here has `display: inline`, thus is treated like text. It thus also observes the `line-height` property which controls how much extra vertical space each line gets. For readability reasons we don't cram lines directly together.

Switching to `display: block` on the `svg` makes the `div` fit exactly, as does setting `line-height: 0` on the `div`.

Comment: I want `display: inline-block` on the svg since don't want it to line break

Comment: You're nesting an SVG inside a div. It's not going to break text any worse than the div already does (which is a block). But, as noted, you have two options. Heck, you can even fit the div's width by setting it to `display: table-cell`.

Comment: In my use case its `div > (svg+text)` So I need the svg to not be `display: block`

Comment: Would be helpful to include that factoid in your question, don't you think? *Still*, you *can* also set `line-height` on the div, as mentioned.

Comment: `display: block` fixed the problem thanks!